# Cyrillic in Palatino-like font

Tags: latex

Is there a way to get Cyrillic characters in a Palatino-like font under LaTeX? It seems the standard fonts (provided by mathpazo or TeX Gyre) only cover the Latin script.

Answer (score 4):

Your choice may depend on what you mean by Palatino-like and whether and how much you're willing to pay for a commercial font.  The open source Linux Libertine font is a serif font that has Cyrillic glyphs, but it's not really Palatino-like:
http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=2&L=1

You could purchase commercial fonts like the family pack of different faces and weights here:
http://www.fonts.com/FindFonts/Detail.htm?pid=4653079&/cgi-bin/MsmGo.exe?grab_id=0&page_id=12025&query=PALATINO&SCOPE=Fonts

In any case you will want to be using XeTeX (or LuaTeX) to automaticaly make easy use of  these fonts, rather than plain LaTeX or pdfTeX.

There are a ton of commercial fonts out there that have Cyrillic character sets, many of which are less expensive than the Linotype Palatino font linked above (although even Linotype could be less if you don't need all the different faces and/or weights).  For an example of some lower priced commercial possibilities check out what's available from Storm Type Foundry:
http://www.stormtype.com/

or just go to an online font superstore like fonts.com and poke around a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for a solution with plain LaTeX, not with XeTeX.

Comment: There are ways to get the fonts to work in LaTeX (see e.g., http://www.rubli.info/linux/latex_opentype.txt ), but I wonder whether you have specific reasons for avoiding XeTeX.  What platform are you on and what software are you running? In many installations (e.g., MiKTeX on Windows) compiling with XeTeX rather than plain LaTex is as simple as flipping a switch.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I usually use XeTeX, but this time I have to use pLaTeX, the Japanese version of LaTeX (XeTeX is still not as good as pLaTeX for typesetting Japanese), and it does not support Unicode nor opentype fonts. This is why I was wondering if there is a Palatino-like font with Cyrillic glyphs (the text I'm typesetting also has some Cyrillic charachtes) provided for plain LaTeX.